# JQuery - POST Method not sending the data

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I am creating a Client server application using AJAX and JavaScript.

I am a beginner in this so therefore I tried with sending basic data with the code that is given in w3schools. [JQuery Example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_post)

But on the server side when I printed the input stream I got this but no data.

```
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 30
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

My server side code looks like this:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
String line;
while((line=stdIn.readLine())!=null)
    System.out.println(line);
```

Why the client side is not sending data?

Edit:

The client side code, it is a basic code taken from w3schools:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/",
        {
          name: "Donald Duck",
          city: "Duckburg"
        },
        function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: would be helpful if you add your *Client-side* code also ?

Comment: Share you client side code as it is problem with client side.

Comment: @AnkitNigam I have added the client side code.